# Applescript to "jump" to designated application and back to previous one?

Tags: macos, applescript

I like to use this script to bring up useful applications that need to be accessed often. I would like this script to return to the previous application when run instead of just hiding it when visible. What code would nee to be changed so that when the “Mail” is visible, it will jump to the previously open application?

```
    set appName to "Mail"

    set appID to bundle identifier of (info for (path to application appName))
    tell application "System Events"
        if not (exists process appName) then
            tell application appID to activate
        else
            if frontmost of process appName then
                set visible of process appName to false
            else
                set frontmost of process appName to true
            end if
        end if
    end tell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any way to get the second frontmost application apart from hacks like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set p to process 1 where frontmost is true
    set visible of p to false
    delay 0.01
    set a to process 1 where frontmost is true
    delay 0.01
    set frontmost of p to true
    a
end tell
```

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke tab using command down
    delay 0.01
    set a to path to frontmost application as text
    delay 0.01
    keystroke tab using command down
    a
end tell
```

You might hide and then show the application though:

```
if (path to frontmost application) is (path to application "Mail") then
    tell application "System Events"
        set visible of process "Mail" to false
        delay 0.01
        set visible of process "Mail" to true
    end tell
else
    activate application "Mail"
end if
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it to switch back and forth between previous and current apps. I tried to implement it with my original script by adding it but had no success. tell application "System Events"
    keystroke tab using command down
    delay 0.01
    set a to path to frontmost application as text
    delay 0.01
    keystroke tab using command down
    a
end tell